# Page Load on Refresh in IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a website and I'm getting a lot of inconsistencies with loading when refreshing a page. Clicking on links functions as expected; no issues there. The problem only occurs when REFRESHING a page. You will notice how it takes forever to load, and in some instances, refuses to load at all.

http://annualreview.com.au/caltex/2012/

The site was built using WordPress 3.5.1 (http://wordpress.org) and Foundation 3.2.5 (http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. I'm out of ideas.

Thanks.

**Update:** This may not be IE related. The problem seems to exist in other browsers as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing any failures on OSX/Chrome OSX/Safari but in both cases the HTML is taking a seriously long time - 5-9s - to turn up. Is this hosted on Wordpress infrastructure, or yours?

Comment: Not seeing any problem with the page load/refresh here.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal The site is hosted on our own business hosting account through VentraIP (http://ventraip.com.au). The site is loading fine in Chrome on OSX for me now as well, so this does seem to be an IE/IE8 issue. I have tried temporarily reverting to the default twentytwelve theme which fixes the problem, so it must be theme related.

Comment: Okay. I've found the source of the problem. When I remove the respond.js script, the issue ceases to exist. But, I need the script in order to maintain responsiveness in IE, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: respond.js does warn about not using @font-face (not sure if that's the problem here) - have you tried http://modernizr.com/ to manage the responsive media queries?

Comment: I replaced Respond.js with the following script and the problem resolved itself. https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: now you need to add the answer and award yourself the bounty ;) Wonder what was causing respond.js to break but the solution you found looks handy

Comment: Works well with Chrome

Comment: No problem detected. You should open the developer tools and see if there is any JS error in IE8

Comment: Sorry, guys. Haven't been on StackOverflow for a few days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced Respond.js with the following script and the problem resolved itself. http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a timing based issue being introduced within respond.js. It may have javascript code that is directly inline in the js file, and is not wrapped in an event such as document.ready. This would cause it to execute immediate as the page loads and reads the js and could cause inconsistent page load behavior depending on how fast or slow things happen.

If this is the case a quick workaround might be to wrap the entire contents of the respond.js file in the document ready event handler so that the code doesn't execute until everything has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //respond.js contents here..
});
```

With that said, I would check the IE or Chrome developer tools console to see if any js errors are happening. If still no luck I would re-trace the page load logic to try to identify where a timing related problem could exist and go from there. You can add console.log entries in your code to help you trace through it at runtime and determine the flow. The log entries may make it obvious as to where the problem originates.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Firebug, there are huge delays in trying to load the images. Each image is blocking until the previous image has been loaded - tried refreshing the page a few times and the images are taking between 1 and 11 seconds every time.

[Image of Firebug results:](https://s17.postimg.org/i3jtmbz1r/firebug_results.jpg)
[image: https://s17.postimg.org/i3jtmbz1r/firebug_results.jpg]

I'm not very knowledgeable in image optimisation, but after a quick search, found a couple of ways you could try to optimise the load times:

- [CSS Sprites](http://alistapart.com/article/sprites) - this is unlikely to be useful to you looking at the dimensions of the images, and may be tricky to implement the image fades, but worth mentioning in case can be implemented elsewhere within the website.
- The other thing you could try, is using other image hosting sites, such as Flickr or Amazon S3. Browsers tend to only let you have 2 connections to the same server at a time (with all your images being on the same server, you're getting the long blocking times), but allow connections to 8 different servers simultaneously, so using the third party sites may improve load time for you.